# Spark Transmitter with flyback driver and good arcs

Tags: rf, transmitter, arc, spark

I recently built a Fly-back Driver with a fly-back transformer and a primary voltage input of 12 volts and the arcs are about an inch long ( i don't know the exact output voltage because I don't have the ability to measure it ). I have heard that in the 1900's they used arcs to transmit Morse. I want to replicate this. I am wondering how I would hook up the antennas to the arc and hooking up the ground and how the arc relates to all of this. I know that there might be some legal issues to this, but I live in the mountains far from many people, maybe a few FM radio users but I just want to test this for a second and I will not be continuously running this, in other words don't restrict me to information because of legal issues because I know the warnings. So how should I connect the arc up to ground and the antenna and is there any other components I need for this?

Comment: aren't chaotic spark transmissions banned by international treaty?

Comment: im just going to do it for a second so it wont matter

Comment: The law is there for our benefit. The length of time you spend violating the law is not a factor, any more than running a traffic light only takes a moment. You can study to gain knowledge, without harming/endangering others.

Comment: I bet you could just use an am radio, I remember hearing car spark plugs through an old am radio in my dads car. Also I am sure you wouldn't get in trouble as long as you aren't trying to use your device for communication, sparks aren't illegal, or most of the welding techniques would be outlawed.

Comment: Major differences from a typical welding operation would be the intentional antenna - and perhaps the tuned circuit as well.  The experiment can probably be conducted *without* an antenna, which would be somewhat more considerate.

Comment: so without an antenna do I need a tuning coil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedi's pictorial 1000 words [from here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/Spark_gap_transmitter_diagram.png) opines:

[image]

And a [very large number of references are here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=spark+transmitter+aerial&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=yKwtUZf6FsWNiAfHxIDgAg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1536&bih=830) some even relevant.